# Is there any sort of programming environment that runs ON an IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I'm just recalling the days when Radio Shack used to sell pocket computers.  (Many moons ago, w/ only a few K of memory.)  They had the ability to write small programs on Pocket computer.  Maybe it's just nostalgic, but I alway thought that was handy. (Through the fog of my memory.)  Is there any capability like that for an Iphone?

Edit:
I can kinda understand not allowing a like a GameBoy emulator on the App-store, it's kinda like saying your ok with people loading "ROMs" and could get them in trouble.  When you start profitting from an Emulator the license holders get pissy, just think about "Bleem" and Sony.  Sony buried those guys.  I suppose Javascript is better than nothing.  What about Java in a sandbox?  Or if they want something they aren't afraid is going to cannibalise there market, a BASIC interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that you are allowed to in the terms of service for the App store.  Isn't this why mono programs have to be staticly compiled if they are going up to the App store.

Comment: Apple will deny any application capable of running arbitrary code. This includes emulators and virtual machines for interpreted languages.

Comment: @Corey D: This may be at least one case where Apple blows goats. (I generally like their computer equipment and OS X, although I was disappointed to see them move to Intel at the same time IBM was coming out with the Cell BBE.  OS X on a CELL would have been wicked cool.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to go off the beaten path, James Long's [blog](http://jlongster.com/blog/2009/06/17/write-apps-iphone-scheme/) details how to run Gambit Scheme code on the iPhone. Load the application once and then load code changes progressively as needed.

In a following blog post, he details how to debug your applications remotely with an REPL. Very cool stuff. Between the simplicity of Scheme and the existing work he's done on his blog, a lot of the work/difficulty involved with developing in a "non-standard" way on the iPhone is taken care of for you. It's worth a shot!

Answer (score 2):

Python is possible:

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-November/686098.html

Comment: It wasn't clear in the link weather this required a hacked Iphone or not.  But if Apple allows it, it definitely has potential.  Just need a slick GUI front end.

Comment: Alas, it apparently requires jailbreaking (I am not an iPhone user, but would not buy one if I had not decided I was OK with jailbreaking it ahead of time - just on principle.)  A related post:  http://www.thelinuxblog.com/reasons-why-you-should-jailbreak-your-iphone/

Comment: Jailbreaking my phone made it much less responsive.  I decided to revert back to the official release for the performance alone.

Comment: Jailbreaking does not in any remote way make it less responsive, use more battery etc. All pure FUD. Installing Jailbreak-only apps like Winterboard will but that goes without saying, and you can always turn said apps off.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing remotely close to that (without Jailbreaking) is Javascript/HTML in Mobile Safari.

Comment: And with jailbreaking, a lot lot more is possible :)

Comment: I suppose Javascript is better than nothing!  I'm guessing no "IDE" exist then.

Answer (score 1):

While "on" your iphone is relative www.tilestack.com is a web based development environment that can produce webapps.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal.app can be compiled for limited distribution (w/o jailbreaking). /bin/sh is a valid programming language. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to set up a node.js programming environment that lets you run your own server on the iPad.  It's also possible to run javascript using the textastic code editor.  See [Is it possible to do programming using iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857441/is-it-possible-to-do-programming-using-iphone/12268340#12268340).